# Add new list items to a List<T> in MVC, Razor, ASP.NET with form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, ienumerable

I am working on an order form. The page loads the previously saved order items into a table. The first row of the table is the add new item row with Html.EditoFor() like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.OrderItems[0].Description)
```

Of course the [0] represents in this case nothing, this is just to demonstrate the goal.
To show the existing items, a for loop is used:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Model.OrderItems.Count; i++)
{ @Html.EditorFor(d => d.OrderItems[i].Description)}
```

The order items are stored in an IEnumerable list with four properties (Desc, Partnum, Cost, Qty).

**The question is:** the editor row is a form and when the user presses the Add button on the page how can that form add the new item to the existing list?

Comment: Some options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796)

Comment: You can't add items to an `IEnumerable`. Use a collection such as a `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it is list. Question title corrected.
@StephenMuecke, thanks, checking those.

Comment: how you are loading OrderItems in your action?

Comment: @SandeepKumar from the controller

Comment: are you loading OrderItems from database or you have a hard coded list?
it would be easy to answer if you share controller code.

Answer (score 0):

you can post your 'new item' to your another action ,the param is your 'new item', you can modify your existing list now